# How to program optional multiple inheritance in Python

Tags: inheritance, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance, pycharm

How to implement multiple inheritance with two classes. One class is optional.

I used a decorator:

```
def optional_inherit(cls):                                                         

    if _config.GDRIVE_HOOK:
        from jinjacms2 import drivecms

        class cls(cls, drivecms.CmsDrive):
            pass
    return cls

@optional_inherit
class JinjaCMS(cmsbase.CmsHandler):

    def get(self):
        ...
```

But? Is there another way?
The class name "cls" in the decorator reports : cls is not an allowed PEP-8 class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found inspiration in [this great article](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/28/improve-your-python-metaclasses-and-dynamic-classes-with-type/):

```
def jinjacms_get(self):         # member function for JinjaCMS class
    ....

if config.GDRIVE_HOOK:          #optional multiple inheritance
    from jinjacms import drivecms
    JinjaCMS = type(str('JinjaCMS'), (drivecms.CmsDrive, cmsbase.CmsHandler), {'get': jinjacms_get})
else:
    JinjaCMS = type(str('JinjaCMS'), (cmsbase.CmsHandler, ), {'get': jinjacms_get})
```

in Python the class hierarchy is defined right to left